# Creating yearly comparison after summarizing datediff in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, comparison, average, datediff, date-difference

I created a report that calculated how many days it took a person to complete a task (datediff) and then calculated the avg. number of days it took a group of people to complete the same task (by summing the datediff and then inserting an "avg." function). The time frame used was set by using a "Start date" and "End date" parameter field.

Now, the end user is asking, "how does that average compare to last year?"

I gave a quick answer by creating a Cross tab where I made the "Start date" 01/01/2018 and the end date 12/09/2019 and then grouped by Year in the columns. That is not an exact year-to-year comparison since this is all of 2018 compared to YTD 2019.

I know there is a better way to do this. Any help is appreciated!

*Each task has a unique ID, a start date, and an end date*

Answer (score 0):

Try using a subreport that shows the same summary data as the primary report, but for a modified set of Start and End Dates.  Link the subreport using both Start Date and End Date, but subtract one year from each value.  This will allow your primary report to show data for 1-1-2019 through 12-09-2019 and the subreport will show 1-1-2018 through 12-09-2018.

Here is the formula to subtract 1 year from a date.

```
DateAdd("yyyy", -1, {@StartDate})
```

You can use this formula in your selection criteria for the subreport or you can create a formula field in the subreport as well, then use that formula field in the selection criteria.

Comment: Would I need to create a formula for "Previous Year" in the subreport? Something like PY = Start Date minus 365?

Comment: A formula will be necessary to subtract a year from a date.  The `DateAdd()` function would be the simplest way to accomplish this.  I have edited my answer to show an example of the formula you will need.

Comment: I have duplicated the report and made 1  Sub-report. I linked the reports by the PARAMETER FIELDS "Start Date" and "End Date". The formula you have above suggests that "Start Date" is a formula field?

Comment: Do I need to add 2 formula fields; one for Start and one for End?

Comment: That depends on how you need to use the date values.  If you only need them one time in the selection criteria of the subreport, then you can just write a single formula for the subreport's selection criteria.  If you think you might need the dates elsewhere within the subreport, then you would be best off creating a formula field for each date.